# iOS -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

I wanted to use `Tesseract` for my project. I have created a new project , added `Tesseract` to my pod file. pod install correctly and my project build perfectly on Emulator device. But on real device the following error occured. Don't know what's going on
**ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason of Problem :** While installing `cocoapod` dependency that were compiled with `ENABLED_BITCODE = YES` and thus it override this settings that create a problem. To solve this , we had to add these lines on our `cocoapod` so that `ENABLED_BITCODE`setting is not overriden during cocoapod dependency installation

```
 post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
         end
     end
 end
```